# Is it possible to return a return value and a result set from a stored procedure using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Looking for suggestions on cleanest way to get the return value and the result set (without passing a referenced parameter to the stored proc).

MY stored procs have return values to show errors, etc and they end with a select statement to get the information.  With regular commands I would create an output parameter which would hold the return value.  I can't change the stored procs in the db so I can't pass a different output parameter other then the return value.

thoughts??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a stored procedure in the LINQ to SQL Data Context designer by dragging it from the Server Explorer, the designer will analyze the sproc to determine if it returns a result set. Unless it features heavy dynamic SQL, it's usually spot on.

If it does, the method generated returns `ISingleResult<T>` where `T` is either a class generated from an analysis of your sproc to fit the shape of the result set, or one you specify in the sproc properties page. Because `ISingleResult` derives from `IEnumerable`, most people do a simple foreach on the result to get their result set. But what most people forget is that `ISingleResult` *also* derives from `IFunctionResult`, which has a property called [`ReturnValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.ifunctionresult.returnvalue.aspx). *This is the return value from the sproc.*

So all you have to do is something along the lines of:

```
using(var dc = new MyDataContext())
{
    var results = dc.MyStoredProcedure();
    var returnValue = (int)results.ReturnValue; // note that ReturnValue is of type object and must be cast.
    foreach(var row in results)
    {
        // process row
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is what I was doing previously but the issue is that these stored procs are now returning custom types so it doesn't automatically create the return value within the custom type.  I'll have a look and see if I can get away with using a generic var type and then converting through code to the custom type.

Comment: @Adam: Do you mean the return value or the result set when you say "returning custom types"?

Comment: I meant result set... I'm just looking through old entries so this is no longer an issue.  I think I just ended up using the var type for the result set because I couldn't get it to use a custom return type for the results AND still have a "return value" as a part of that return type.