# Can I receive both the return value and resultset from a procedure using Linq to sql?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

(Did anyone modify my question?)

I found that when a procedure does not select and only includes `Return 1;`, the auto generated datacontext code is like this:

```
IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, 
    ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));

return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
```

but when I prepend a statement `SELECT GETDATE() AS Date,'Boolean' AS Name;Return 1;`, it appears like this:

```
IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, 
    ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));

return ((ISingleResult<Test_GetReturnValue2Result>)(result.ReturnValue));
```

Seems like I cannot get the return value from a procedure when it returns a resultset.

I would like to be unable to access both the result set (specified by `SELECT GETDATE() AS Date,'Boolean' AS Name;`) **and** the return value (specified by `Return 1;`)

Can anyone handle this (in an easier way)?

Comment: The question is very unclear.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: everyone know that procedure can return an interger value by "Return" statement and some resultset(or recordset or datatable) through "Select" statment.but I found that linq2sql cannot handle it when the procedure return them both.

Comment: Seems like linq2sql has no way to receive them both in one query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to return a return value and a result set from a stored procedure using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191461/is-it-possible-to-return-a-return-value-and-a-result-set-from-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191461/is-it-possible-to-return-a-return-value-and-a-result-set-from-a-stored-procedure

Comment: Thank you,I think this will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the **IMultipleResults** interface :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.imultipleresults.aspx

For sure you can do what you want with that, maybe not exactly the way you wanted.